# Share resources across projects in Maven - No message found under code '1' for locale ''

Tags: java, spring, maven

In the POM where is the resource to share:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>bundle</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.properties</include>

      </includes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

in the target\classes appears the locale folder with the file messages.properties

POM project to use the resource from the other project

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-remote-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <resourceBundles>
                            <resourceBundle>org.apache:apache-jar-resource-bundle:1.4</resourceBundle>﻿
                        </resourceBundles>﻿
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

the xml where i want read the resource

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename">
            <value>locale\messages</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Any idea how resolve the following error:

> 160421 14:16:49,104 WARN qtp1526730726-18
>   org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource -
>   ResourceBundle [locale\messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't
>   find bundle for base name locale\messages, locale  2016-04-21
>   14:16:49.125:WARN:oejs.ServletHandler:qtp1526730726-18: 
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found
>   under code '1' for locale ''.

Comment: Forward-slash `/` is more typical than backslash `\ ` for these sorts of things. Suggest you try `locale/messages`.